# Not able to open Swagger UI in Micronaut application when run from JAR

Tags: java, swagger-ui, micronaut

I have a Micronaut Application and I want to use Swagger to show the documentation of the API. This link [OpenAPI/Swagger Support](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-openapi/latest/guide/index.html) tells all the changes that have to be done to enable the Swagger UI. For adding the system properties I have added the script given in Gradle for Java section. But the problem is that when I run the application from the IntelliJ IDEA, I am able to access the UI page but when I assemble the project into a JAR file(and run it using java -jar filename.jar), it doesn't show any output. But in both the cases I was able to access the swagger's yml file through 8080:swagger/application-name-1.0.yml.

On further inspection, I found that when I ran it through IntelliJ, the swagger UI was initiating a request for the yml file(and two rows with appear with Response code200) and thereafter would return 304 on refresh but the UI page would load. But when I ran the jar file, I will see a only a single response of swagger UI which doesn't initiate a request for the yml file and therefore the screen remains blank.

It is important to not that I have added the router and the intercept url map in the application.yml file. And there is JVM fork and compile option for enabling the views.

What should I do so that I get access to the Swagger UI when the Micronaut application is started from the JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple Micronaut project to test it and it works. You can clone this repo https://github.com/dcalap/my-openapi-app to use it.

In the README there is a gif showing how the jar is serving the Swagger UI.

Comment: Now I also have this issue. Looked into your source but did not figure out the essential point. I am using gradle and Kotlin.

Comment: Ok I guess it is the compiler args. But I can't get them passed on my side with build.gradle.kts